# convergence of first passage time of sequences of uniformly convergence functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability

For a sequence of Lipschitz continuous nondecreasing real-valued functions $f_n$ on $[0,1]$, such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly. $f_n(0)=0$ and $f(0)=0$. the first passsage time at $0$ is defined as
$$\tau^n=\inf\{t\in[0,1]: f_n(t)>0\}$$
$$\tau=\inf\{t\in[0,1]: f(t)>0\}$$
I want to show that $\tau^n\to \tau$. If not, is it possible for some $\delta>0$, such that $\liminf \tau^n+\delta\ge\tau$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Consider the sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which satifies $f_n(0)=0$, $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ for $x \geq 1/n$ and which is linear on $(0,1/n)$. The sequence converges uniformly to $f=0$. Then $\tau^n=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ whereas $\tau=\inf(\emptyset)=\infty$.

It **is** possible to show that $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \tau^n \leq \tau$$ but this is the best you can expect under the given assumptions, I think.

Comment: Thank you very much! The part that $\limsup \tau^n\le \tau $ is not hard. BTW, what if I add an assumption that $f(1)>0$, say $f(1)=1$?

Comment: @YYF That's not going to help. Consider e.g. a piecewise linear functions $f_n$ with $f_n(0)=0$, $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ for $x \in (1/n,1/2)$ and $f_n(1)=1$. Then $f_n \to f(x) := \max\{0,x-1/2\}$ uniformly, $\tau^n=0$ and $\tau=\frac{1}{2}$. Note that we can replace $1/2$ by any number, say, $r \in (0,1)$, and so $\tau-\limsup_{n \to \infty} \tau^n$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: thank you so much!